# Remove number forever from an array

Tags: ios

I have a fixed set of numbers in NSArray. Example: I have 10 numbers: 1, 20, 31, 33, 54,66, 77,87,90,99. (these are basically unique serial numbers)

When someone types a number, I want to validate if its one of those numbers and remove it from the list FOREVER. As in, suppose I type 20, it should say "Valid" and 20 should be removed. If i type 20 again, it should say, "Invalid number". I have been able to validate and remove them. However, how do i remove them forever? By 'forever', I mean, if 2 people have my app on their phones, and Phone1 has already used the code 20, then for Phone2, it should say code is invalid.

Is there a way I can do this? Probably by connecting to the internet?

Comment: Yeah, you're going to have to "connect to the internet" for this one.

Comment: you have to back-end somewhere which stores the serial numbers, and each instance of the application needs to fetch the information from the server directly. but if you ask this question like this, it indicates that problem is over on you, and you might ask a professional developer to solve such an issue. (friendly advice only).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to hold the list of numbers centrally. When a device requests one, it will have to ask the server, which will remove it from the list then respond to say it has done so. Future requests for the same number should be rejected.

There are plenty of free backend services, like Parse or Heroku, which will be a good place to start with.